# How to set Crtrl+r to execute commands in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

How can I set RStudio to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (in addition to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to execute commands?

https://community.rstudio.com/t/bring-ctrl-r-back/1846 suggests editing the "rstudio_bindings.json" file, but I can't find the file.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts gives instructions to add using  from the menu options. I tried to add `"Ctrl+Enter|Ctrl+R"` as suggested in the first link but this is not accepted. At the bottom of the page it describes how the bindings are saved at `~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/rstudio_commands.json` or `~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/editor_commands.json`. I cannot find either of these files.

How can I do this?

R version 3.4.2
RStudio Version 1.1.383
Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following advice from https://community.rstudio.com/t/bring-ctrl-r-back/1846,
you have to edit the file `~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/rstudio_bindings.json` with

```
{
    "executeCode" : "Ctrl+Enter|Ctrl+R"
}
```

These directories and file already existed on Ubuntu, however, neither the file nor any of the directories existed on my Windows partition. So needed to create the nested directories `.R/rstudio/keybindings`, and then create the `json` file shown above, and save it as `rstudio_bindings.json`.

(aside: Windows didn't like trying to name a new folder of `.R` (the leading dot gave problems), but you can get round this by naming `.R.` , as the trailing dot is removed [from here](https://superuser.com/questions/64471/create-rename-a-file-folder-that-begins-with-a-dot-in-windows) )